# What should I do to use function interface on Class property method

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

As you can see, in the Request Class, there are get(), put(), delete(), post() methods, and each of them has quite a few parameters. So I just want to use one interface.

```java
interface fetchParam {
  (
    url: string,
    params?: string | object | [],
    alwaysBack?: boolean,
    options?: object,
    resolveResult?: boolean,
  ): {}
}

class Request {
  constructor() {}

  fetchApi(url, method, params, alwaysBack, options, resolveResult) {
     return new Promise((res, rej) => { 
       // do somthing
     })
  }

  get(url, params, alwaysBack, options, resolveResult) {
    return this.fetchApi(url, 'get', params, alwaysBack, options, resolveResult)
  }

  post(url, params, alwaysBack, options, resolveResult) {
    return this.fetchApi(url, 'post', params, alwaysBack, options, resolveResult)
  }

  put(url, params, alwaysBack, options, resolveResult) {
    return this.fetchApi(url, 'put', params, alwaysBack, options, resolveResult)
  }

  delete(url, params, alwaysBack, options, resolveResult) {
    return this.fetchApi(url, 'delete', params, alwaysBack, options, resolveResult)
  }


}
```

I do not want to like this, too cumbersome

```
get(url: string, params?: string | object | [], alwaysBack?: boolean) {
    // do somthing
}
```

so, what should I do?

Comment: What are actually asking here?  Are you asking how to declare one flexible interface in TypeScript?  Or are you asking for an efficient way to declare one common interface that all your methods use?  Or asking something else?

Comment: Dear @jfriend00 , I want to declare one common interface for the methods which have the same params

Comment: I don't think you are looking for a shared interface, you just want to reduce the code duplication, right?

Answer (score 0):

my idea is to wrap it into an object

```
get({ url, params, alwaysBack }: fetchParam) {
// do something
}
```

Comment: good idea, but when I use it, I must  write the keys for params
get({ulr: ' ', params: ' ', alwaysBack: ' '}).then()